# How to redirect to a URL in Apex?

Tags: apex

I wish to override the New standard button on a related list to skip the page that allows one to choose a record type and to go straight to a page in edit mode.

In order to do this I must choose a VF page to point the button to. All I want on that page it to go exactly to the correct page. I wish to know how to go this in Apex. I tried using HTML refresh but it only takes me to the list view despite I use the exact URL for the correct record type like this https://eu3.salesforce.com/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9

So this code below doesn't seem to do the trick, the question is what does?

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Grant_Proposal__c" showHeader="false" >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=https://eu3.salesforce.com/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using apex custom controller and apex:page **action** attribute.

For example:

```
public class RedirectController{
    public RedirectController(){
    }
    public PageReference redirectToSomePage(){
        PageReference result_page = Page.MyCustomPage;
        result_page.getParameters().put('secret_param', 'secret_value');
        return result_page;
    }
}
```

And then use next page:

```
<apex:page controller="RedirectController" action="{!redirectToSomePage}" >
</apex:page>
```

You can also put custom logic into that method.

More information about that:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000094v2IAA